# React reselect - toJS is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js, reselect

I am getting an error in the selectors of a react application when using toJS with the reselect library.
I tried importing `toJS` as well as not importing it and I get the error no matter what.

> nodeCreationWindow.get(...).toJS is not a function

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'
import { toJS } from 'immutable'

const selectNodeCreationWindow = () => (state) => state.get('nodeCreationWindow')

const selectNodes = () => createSelector(
  selectNodeCreationWindow(),
  (nodeCreationWindow) => {
    return nodeCreationWindow.get('nodes').toJS()
  }
)

const selectTags = () => createSelector(
  selectNodeCreationWindow(),
  (nodeCreationWindow) => nodeCreationWindow.get('tags').toJS()
)

const selectSuggestions = () => createSelector(
  selectNodeCreationWindow(),
  (nodeCreationWindow) => nodeCreationWindow.get('suggestions').toJS()
)


export {
  selectNodes,
  selectTags,
  selectSuggestions
}
```

Comment: Try `var tmp = nodeCreationWindow.toJS(); return temp.nodes`

Answer (score 1):

I think that value returned by `nodeCreationWindow.get('nodes')` is already a pure JS object so it doesn't have toJS method.

Besides, remove this line:

```
import { toJS } from 'immutable'
```

because `toJS` is not exported by Immutable module but attached to Immutable objects